# The product rule on $C[0, 1]$ for different norms

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

If $f_n → f$ and $g_n → g$, does $f_n g_n → fg$ in the space $C[0, 1]$ for the norms $||.||_1$ and $||.||_∞$

Give a proof or counterexample for each.

I know that $||.||_1$ is the sum of the magnitudes of the values, and $||.||_∞$ is the biggest magnitude of the values. From this I assume $||.||_1$ DOES work whilst $||.||_∞$ doesn't, but I am unsure on if this is true, and if so, how to show it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not "sum", integral..  $\|f\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f(x)|\; dx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, both of your guesses are incorrect.

To see the $\|\,\|_1$ result fails, let

$$f_n(x)= \frac{1}{[\ln (n+1)(x+1/n)]^{1/2}}.$$

Verify that $f_n\to 0$ in the $\|\,\|_1$-norm. However $f_n\cdot f_n$ does not converge to $0\cdot 0=0$ in the $\|\,\|_1$-norm, as you can check.

The $\|\,\|_\infty$ result is true. This is classic and is easier to show. We have $f_n\to f,g_n\to g$ uniformly on $[0,1].$ This implies there is a uniform bound on all of these functions. Now use

$$f_ng_n-fg= f_ng_n-fg_n + fg_n-fg$$

to see $f_ng_n\to fg$ uniformly.

Comment: Is it enough to say that $g_n ( f_n -f) + f( g_n -g)$ converges, as it equals $0$ if it does, and both brackets coverge?

Comment: There is a constant $M$ such that $\|f_n\|_\infty,\|g_n\|_\infty,\|f\|_\infty,\|g\|_\infty$ are all $\le M.$ Thus the $\sup$ norm of the expression you mention is $\le M\|f_n-f\|_\infty + M\|g_n-g\|_\infty,$ and this $\to 0.$

Answer (score 2):

For a counterexample to the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm, consider
$$f_n(t) = \begin{cases} n-n^3t, &\text{ if } t \in \left[0,\frac1{n^2}\right]\\
0, &\text{ if } t \in \left[\frac1{n^2},1\right]\\
\end{cases}$$

Then $\|f_n\|_1 = \frac1{2n} \to 0$ but $\|f_n^2\|_1 = \frac13 \not\to 0$.

Comment: I am struggling on how to calculate $||f_n||_1 = \frac{1}{2n} $ and$ ||{f_n}^{2}||_1 = \frac{1}{3}$. Any guidance?

Comment: @rl4y The functions $f_n$ and $f_n^2$ are supported on $\left[0,\frac1{n^2}\right]$ so $$\|f_n\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f_n(t)|\,dt = \int_0^{\frac1{n^2}} (n-n^3t)\,dt = \left(nt - n^3 \frac{t^2}2\right)\Bigg|_0^{\frac1{n^2}} = \frac1{2n},$$
$$\|f_n^2\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f_n(t)|^2\,dt = \int_0^{\frac1{n^2}} (n-n^3t)^2\,dt = \left(n^2t -n^4t^2 + n^6\frac{t^3}{3} \right)\Bigg|_0^{\frac1{n^2}} = \frac1{3}.$$

Comment: @rl4y Also for $\|f_n\|_1$ notice that the graph of $f_n$ is a right triangle with legs $n$ and $\frac1{n^2}$ so its area is $\frac1{2n}$.

Comment: Thank you, that is clear. I was looking at the wrong definition for the 1-norm!

Answer (score 1):

> In my earlier answer, I've addressed only the uniform norm; as, @zhw. noted, I sloppily missed the $\|.\|_1$-norm (shame on me) which zhw. did solve. And still, to make up for my misdeed, let me present another example which shows that $\|.\|_1$-norm is not continuously multiplicative.

Let $\,a>0\,$ and $\,0<b\le 1\,$ be two otherwise arbitrary reals. Define:

$$ \forall_{x\in[0;1]}\quad F_{a\,b}(x)
         \ :=\ \max(a\!\cdot\!(b-x)\ \ 0) $$

hence
$$ \forall_{x\in[0;1]}\quad F^2_{a\,b}(x)\ =
                \ \min(a^2\!\cdot\!(b-x)^2\ \ 0) $$

so that

$$ \|F_{a\ b}\|_{_1}\ =\ \frac 12\cdot a\cdot b^2 $$

and

$$ \|F^2_{a\ b}\|_{_1}\ =\ \frac 13\cdot a^2\cdot b^3  $$

Define

$$ \forall_{n\in\Bbb N}\quad f_n := F_{_{n^5\,\ n^{-3}}} $$

Then

$$ \|f_n\|_{_1} = \frac 1{2\cdot n}\quad\to\quad 0 $$
while
$$ \|f^2_n\|_{_1} = \frac n3\quad\to\quad\infty $$

This shows the mentioned lack of continuity.   ***Great!***