# Counterexample for why the $||\cdot||_1$ norm doesn't work for the product rule i.e. $f_n \to f$, $g_n \to g$ $\implies f_ng_n \to fg $ in C[0,1].

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Is the product rule  $f_n \to f$, $g_n \to g$ $\implies f_ng_n \to fg $ true in C[0,1]?
It depends on the norm.

I have to examine the 1-norm $||\cdot||_1$.

I know this isn't true but I am struggling to come up with a simple counterexample on [0,1].

So far I have seen similar threads on here giving counterexamples however I don't understand them. See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3489280/the-product-rule-on-c0-1-for-different-norms).

Can anyone come up with a good counterexample and show detailed working as to why it works? Thank you.

Comment: What about verifying e.g. mechandroid's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f_n=g_n$ piece-wise linear defined by $f_n(0)=f_n(1/n^2)=f_n(1)=0$ and $f_n(1/2n^2)=n$.

$\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise and for $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$to the always vanishing map.

However

$$\Vert f_n g_n \Vert_1 = \int_0^1 \vert f_n g_n \vert = \int_0^1f_n^2 = \frac{1}{3} \neq 0 = \Vert fg \Vert_1$$